# Adding count of Holiday days to dates between

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2012/11/01'
SET @EndDate = '2012/11/05'


SELECT
  (DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
   +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate)   = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Help to add # of holiday days to this solution? If there are any Holiday days between your start and end dates. Assuming I do have a table called BICalendar with a column isHoliday and value = 1 if that date is a holiday.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer the question:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2012/11/01'
SET @EndDate = '2012/11/05'

SELECT (DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2) -- To calculate the number of weekend dates between the two input dates
       + (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) --If the Start date is Sunday, then add one to adjust for non-working days
       + (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) --If the End date is Saturday, then add one to adjust for non-working days
       - (SELECT COUNT(*) --Minus the number of holiday dates between the two dates
          FROM BICalendar
          WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @STartDate AND @EndDate
                AND isHoliday = 1);
```

---

I suspect what you're trying to do is calculate the number of working days between the two dates? If so, the below solution should also work:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME    
SET @StartDate = '2021-05-01'
SET @EndDate = '2021-05-15'

SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) --To calculate the number of days between the two dates
       - (DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2) -- To remove the weekends between the two dates
       + (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) --If the Start date is Sunday, then add one to adjust for non-working days
       + (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) --If the End date is Saturday, then add one to adjust for non-working days
       - (SELECT COUNT(*) --Minus the number of holiday dates between the two dates
          FROM BICalendar
          WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @STartDate AND @EndDate
                AND isHoliday = 1);
```